# Is there a way to convert a python class into bytes?

Tags: python, networking, lan, python-class

I want to send a python class from one computer to the other. In order to send data, it must be in byte form. I know I can do this with dictionaries, but I was wondering if there is a way to convert a class into bytes? I'd prefer to use something other than pickle, because I need something that is fast and efficient.

Thanks

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'd prefer not to use pickling because it tends to be slower.

Comment: Then please ask a more specific question. You asked if there is a way to convert a class into bytes, and the answer is "yes, for example pickle".

Comment: Also, slower compared to what? Did you measure it against something else?

Comment: @mkrieger1 slower compared to converting a dictionary to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/).
Those are the simplest libraries for Python serialization.

Comment: I am creating a game, and I need something that is fast and efficient. Pickling is slow, what about jsonpickle?

Comment: @LD it should be even slower. You are doing a network game replication, right? So you need to transfer data, like, every game frame? Then I would suggest creating a manual serialization when you gather only the most important data. Yes, it is a lot of work, but I think this is the only way to do it as fast as possible in Python.

Comment: Ok, I will probably stick to using dictionaries then. Thanks